# Winform - How to make 3 rows with different colors

Tags: forms, winforms, devexpress

I am trying to make a Form with 3 rows, and make one of the rows with differnet color. The thing is when I try it, the row is not fully color`d, and the edges get the default background color.
Example:
http://puu.sh/i910v/51a6e5699a.png

How I want it to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv2Rj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `BorderStyle` property of the form to `None`. This will remove the borders and the title bar, showing only the client area on which you are painting.

However to get the X (close) button at the top right, you'd have to place a button there yourself and close the application when pressed.